# Inner join vs separate statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, database-performance

I am trying to get some more context on this out of curiosity. So far when I run 2 separate sql statements I find in SQL Profiler that I have no CPU cycles, less reads and less duration than taking the script and using Inner join. Is this a typical case, I am looking for help to understand this better.

Simple example:

```
SELECT *  FROM dbo.ChargeCode 

SELECT *  FROM dbo.ChargeCodeGroup
```

vs

```
SELECT *  
FROM dbo.ChargeCode c 
INNER JOIN dbo.ChargeCodeGroup cc ON c.ChargeCodeGroupID = cc.ChargeCodeGroupID
```

From what I guess is that inner join cost extra CPU cycles because its doing a nested loop. Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: No, you are not.  Your queries do very different things -- one gets the contents of two different tables, the other gets one row that combines things.  Second, databases in general and SQL Server in particular are good at optimizing joins, and "nested loop" is only one option.

Comment: Nested Loop, Merge, Hash Lookup, there are many ways of joining data depending on the statistics of your data and available indexes.  They all do indeed take resources, compared to selecting *(and doing nothing to or with)* two completely independent data sets, but that's because something is being *done* to those data-sets and so you're getting a different result *(nothing is free)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that you're doing two different things here. In your 1st example you're retrieving 2 separate entities. In your second example, your asking the RDBMS to combine (join) 2 entities into a single result set.

A `join` is one of the most powerful capabilities of an RDBMS - and it will (usually) do it as efficiently as it possibly can - but that's not to say it's free or cheap.

Comment: +1 : I would go as far as saying that it is a fundamental concept within *Relational* Databases; it's in the name.  Also, normalisation is another fundamental concept, and that *requires* joins to recombine the data into useful results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
```

must scan whole table.
If there are indexes on `ChargeCodeGroupID` column on either table, it will be much faster for INNER JOIN to only scan index. (By their name, I guess there are). Of course, if there is no index on either `ChargeCodeGroupID` column, second query is slower than the first one.